# MySQL: How to keep entire myisam table in memory?

Tags: mysql, memory, myisam

I have a lot of RAM (1 gb) on my server, and I have a table (100 mb) that I would like to increase the speed of. Is it possible to keep the entire table in memory (while keeping it MYISAM)? Would this make things faster (I already have the proper indexes).

Thanks

Comment: i question this approach if you get 20 visitors at once then your a you've already reached and passed your system resources, what would you do if you get 100 visitors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better suggestion will be increase query cache size, let mysql do the internal optimization

more details - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Query cache will not work though, when the application uses prepared statements. Just a little thing to remember.

Comment: @ajreal: what type of query cache size would you recommend for a 1 gb MySQL server with a main table that is 100 mb? there are also a few other tables that are used once-in-a-while.  also, quick question: does the query cache for a table's queries get invalidated after an insert to that table?

Comment: @DanielSchneller: Why does it not work for prepared statements? I don't completely understand prepared statements, but I thought they were "better" because mysql did some kind of precompilation for the statements. Do you recommend not using prepared statements in the future?

Comment: @eric - the query cache purged if there is write operation, this served almost all your purpose ... read that article to monitor query cache hit rate

Comment: The query cache in MySQL is a very simple implementation. It is a simple string match of queries it has received before. Prepared statments are indeed better - for performance, but mostly for security! They effectively prevent code injection when you have user provided filter values. The basic idea is that instead of you concatenating a query string with all parameters already put in, you use question marks in the WHERE clause and later fill in the values. That counteracts the exact string match of the query cache. The MySQL manual has more info on prepared statements.

Comment: **Before 5.1.17, the query cache is not used for prepared statements** , so to enjoy both benefits, upgrade does the trick

Comment: Interesting, did not know that it was now working with prep statements, too.

Comment: The URL has changed. Here are docs on query cache: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html

Answer (score 5):

If you have lots of memory in the machine and you use it for MySQL primarily, the OS should take care of that. With MyISAM the idea is to let the filesystem keep the pages in its cache that are mostly needed. With lots of RAM, chances increase that your table will not hit the disk very much anyway.

This is IMHO even better than trying to make the table of type MEMORY, because then you would have to worry about writes - those should usually be persistent anyway.

So in the end, unless the machine is under much concurrent memory pressure from other apps than the MySQL server - in which case 1GB would not seem to much for a server nowadays - you will probably not have to do anything to achieve your goal :)

Answer (score 4):

You can change the table engine to MEMORY and it will store the full table in memory.

Comment: If database server power tripped ... data will be?

Comment: All the contents of a table with engine = memory will be lost. 

They are only useful for store (in fact, very quickly) temporary values.

To set this values:

ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = memory;