# How to avoid reloading big data on program start

Tags: c++, database, perl, optimization, file-io

My question is all about tips and tricks. I'm currently working on project, where I have one very big(~1Gb) file with data. First, I need to **extract** data. This extraction takes 10 mins. Then I do **calculations**. Next calculation depends on previous. Let's call them calculation1, calculation2 and so on. Assuming, that I've done extraction part right, I currently face two problems:

1. Every time I launch program it works 10 mins least. I cannot avoid it, so I have to plan debugging.
2. For every next calculation it takes more time.

Thinking of first problem, I assumed, that some sort of database may help, if database is faster, than reading file, which I doubt.

Second problem might be overcomed if I split my big program in smaller programs, each of which will do: *read file-do stuff-write file*. So next stage always can read file from previous, for debug. But it introduces many wasted code for file I/O.

I think that both these problems could be solved by some strategy like: write, and test extract module, than launch it and let it extract all data into RAM. Than write calculation1, and launch it to somehow **grab data directly** from RAM of extract module. And so on with every next calculation. So my questions are:

1. Are there tips and tricks to minimize loads from files?
2. Are there ways to share RAM and objects between programs?

By the way I write this task on Perl because I need it quick, but I'll  rewrite it on C++ or C# later, so any language-specific or language-agnostic answers welcome.

Thank you!

[EDIT]

File of data does not change it is like big immutable source of knowledge. And it is not exactly 1Gb and it does not take 10 minutes to read it. I just wanted to say, that file is big and time to read it is considerable. On my machine 1 Gb read+parse file into right objects takes about minute. Which is still pretty bad.

[/EDIT]

Comment: Consider gzipping the file to tradeoff CPU for reduced IO. Also, how many columns? Are the data changing or stable? Run a local copy of memcached? Or map the file to memory? It all depends on what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Consider a pipeline architecture.  One thread reads the data; when enough data is read, it wakes up the computation thread.  The computation get the data and produces results.  It sends or notifies the "Writing" thread of the results.  The writing thread outputs the results.  Remember these three activities are happening "simultaneously".  Much like shoving stuff through a pipe.

Comment: Fastest solution is to buy another 16GB of ram and run ramdisk

Comment: I'm confused! 1GB used to be big but definitely isn't anymore. Taking 10 minutes to read 1GB of data is definitely too slow. On a 10GB ethernet card you get more than your file worth every second and although it may not be trivial program keep up with this rate. You may need to reconsider your data structure.
Of course, you could build your data structure in shared memory and have one process cling to the data while others are simply reading it. Reasonably simple to do with C++. I have no idea how to do it with perl (perl isn't my primary language).

Comment: Try profiling your code during the extract phase.  It will help you identify what is taking so long.  Devel::NYTProf is the gold standard in perl profilers these days.

Comment: This sounds like a good candidate to import your data to a database such as MySQL, this will allow you to have data laoded into memmory, properly indexed is setup correctly, and accessible from multiple processess/languages.

Comment: Is database faster? Because it seems to me, that reading from database is similar to reading from file.

Comment: It's possible to use SysV shared memory to transport data between processes. Have a look at the module IPC::Shareable on CPAN. Also, think about the file format. Parsing it probably takes much more time than just getting the data into your process from the outside (and databases definitely have that problem too). And as already said, do profile so you _know_ where the time is spent, and thus what part to optimize.

Comment: What kind of data is stored in your large file? If it is mostly numbers, and you have a DirectX 11 capable video card even if you are not on a windows machine, you should be able to use HLSL Compute Shaders to store and process the data after the file is read. I am not sure if GLSL has something similar but they could. You would need a fairly new video card with at least 1-2GB of Video Ram. It is faster to compute data there then across the bus and you have less chances for cache misses. This depends on a proper batch class for sending the data over to the graphics card for computation...

Comment: (continued...) Once the computations are done you can pass the information back in batches to your local application and either store them into structures or write them to a file/s. Both HLSL & GLSL work very efficient with 4x4 matrices using floats or doubles due to the architecture of the GPU and onboard video ram.

Answer (score 1):

On my current system Perl copies the whole 1GB file in memory in 2 seconds. So I believe your problem is not reading the file but parsing it.

So the straightforward solution I can think of is to *preparse it* by, for instance, converting your data into actual *code source*. I mean, you can prepare your data and *hardcode it* in your script directly (using another file of course).

However, if *reading* is an actual problem (which I doubt) you can use database that store the data in the memory ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343225/mysql-how-to-keep-entire-myisam-table-in-memory)). It will be faster anyway just because your database reads the data once upon starting and you don't restart your database as often as your program.

Answer (score 1):

The idea for solving this type of problems can be as follows:

Go for 3 programs:

- Reader
- Analyzer
- Writer

and exchange data between them using shared memory.

For that big file I guess you have considerable amount of data of one object type which you can store in circular buffer in shared memory (I recommend using boost::interprocess).

Reader will continuously read data from the input file and store it in shared memory.
In the meantime, once is enough data read for doing calculations, the Analyzer will start processing it and store results into another circular buffer shared memory file.
Once there are some calculations in the second shared memory the Writer will read them and store them into final output file.

You need to make sure all the processes are synchronized properly so that they do their job simultanouesly and you don't lose the data (the data is not being overwritten before is processed or saved into final file).

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer doqtor gives, but to prevent data from being overwritten, a nice helper class to enable and disable critical sections of code within a thread will do the trick.

```
// Note: I think sealed may be specific to Visual Studio Compiler.
//       CRITICAL_SECTION is defined in Windows.h - If on another OS, 
//       look for similar structure.
class BlockThread sealed {
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION* m_pCriticalSection;

public:
    explicit BlockThread( CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection );
    ~BlockThread();

private:
    BlockThread( const BlockThread& c );
    BlockThread& operator=( const BlockThread& c ); // Not Implement
};

BlockThread::BlockThread( CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection ) {
    m_pCriticalSection = &criticalSection;
}

BlockThread::~BlockThread() {
    LeaveCriticalSection( m_pCriticalSection
}
```

A class such as this would allow you to block specific threads if you are within the bounds of a critical section where shared memory is being used 
and another thread currently has access to it. This will cause this thread 
of code to be locked until the current thread is done its work and this
class goes out of scope.

To use this class with in another class is fairly simple: in the class that you
want to block a thread within its .cpp file you need to create a static variable of this type and call the API's function to initialize it. Then
you can use the BlockThread class to lock this thread.

SomeClass.cpp

```
#include "SomeClass.h"
#include "BlockThread.h" 

static CRITICAL_SECTION s_criticalSection;

SomeClass::SomeClass {
    // Do This First
    InitializeCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );

    // Class Stuff Here      
}

SomeClass::~SomeClass() {
    // Class Stuff Here

    // Do This Last
    DeleteCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );
}

// To Use The BlockThread
SomeClass::anyFunction() {
    // When Your Condition Is Met & You Know This Is Critical
    // Call This Before The Critical Computation Code.
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
}
```

And that is about it, once this object goes out of scope the static member
is cleaned up within the objects destructor and when this object goes out
of scope so does the BlockThread class and its Destructor cleans it up there.
And now this shared memory can be used. You would usually want to use this class if you are traversing over containers to either add, insert, or find and access elements when this data is a shared type.

As for the 3 different threads running in memory on the same data set a good concept is to have 3 or 4 buffers each about 4MB in size and have them work in a rotating order. Buff1 gets data then Buff2 gets data, while Buff2 is getting data Buff 1 is either parsing the data it or passing it off to be stored for computation, then Buff1 waits until Buff3 or 4 is done, pending on how many buffers you have. Then this process starts again. This is the same principle that is used with Sound Buffers when reading in sound files for doing an Audio Stream, or sending batches of triangles to a graphics card. Another words it is a Batch type process.